# Default secondary ordering in Django Models and QuerySets- any reason to specify the primary key?

Tags: django

I want QuerySets for a particular model to be primarily ordered by an `order` field value, and then secondarily ordered by the primary key, `id` (i.e., order of creation). But `id` appears to be the default secondary ordering when the `order` fields are equivalent, and I'm wondering whether its necessary to specify `id` at all in my `ordering` Meta declaration.

Is there any reason to specify "id" in the `ordering` Meta setting for my model, or will it always be the default? Put another way, is the default ordering by primary key merely a side effect of my particular database that I'm using, or can this behavior be relied upon without explicitly specifying it?

E.g.,

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['order']
```

vs.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['order', 'id']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should absolutely include 'id' if that's the behaviour you need. For example, the Postgres docs say:

> If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce.

I'd be wary of using an auto increment key in that way though, they're best used just in the way they're intended, as a way of uniquely identifying a row. I'd suggest:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order', '-created']
```

Comment: This is correct--if you don't specify an ordering, the DBMS can return rows any any order.  Often this works out to be the order in which they were inserted, which may correspond to the PK ordering when using an auto-increment PK, but that is not guaranteed and will not always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort dictionaries in your templates by using templatefilter dictsort, [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-dictsort)

Comment: thank you for your response but it does not answer my question.